# UITableViewCell not showing UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to implement a chat Lobby in my application. I have a `UITableViewCell` that has a label added to it programatically. Upon firing up though, nothing shows. This is my code for the `ViewController` containing the `UITableView`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

    private var ContactNames = [String]()
    private var ContactPicturesURLs = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var ChatsTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ChatsTableView.dataSource = self
        ChatsTableView.delegate = self
        self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        populateActiveChats()
    }

    private func populateActiveChats()
    {
        let loggedOnUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(loggedOnUserID!)

            // Retrieve the products and listen for changes
        ref.observe(.value, with:
                { (snapshot) in

                    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    {
                        // Code to execute when new product is added
                        let chatValueDictionary = child.value as? NSDictionary

                        self.AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: chatValueDictionary)
                        self.DispatchQueueFunc()

                    }
            })
    }

    func AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: NSDictionary!)
    {
        let contactName = chatAsDictionary["userName"] as! String        
        self.ContactNames.append(contactName)
    }

    func DispatchQueueFunc()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.ChatsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return ContactNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = ChatsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chat_room_cell", for: indexPath) as! PrivateChatUITableViewCell

        var index = indexPath.row
        cell.ContactName.text = ContactNames[index]

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        chatIndexToLoad = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_to_chatroom", sender: self)
    }

    var chatIndexToLoad: Int = -1

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "segue_to_chatroom")
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! PrivateChatViewController
            destination.senderId = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation?.uid
            destination.senderDisplayName = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation?.displayName

        }
    }

}
```

This is the code for my `TableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class PrivateChatUITableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var ContactName: UILabel!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit()
    {
        ContactName = UILabel()

        self.addSubview(ContactName)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        let margins = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        ContactName.center = self.center

    }
}
```

Yet my Cell shows blank, if it does show at all:

[image: TableView]

I did debug my code and made sure that the cell gets text to show in its Label, so it's not empty, as seen in this picture:

[image: Cell not empty]

Does anyone have a solution for the label not appearing ?

Also, I debugged the `commonInit` function in the `PrivateChatUITableViewCell`, and it does hit the `addSubView` and constraints commands

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of your initialization in the table cell. It seems like you have a frame zero label in the table. You should set the position of the label by using NSLayoutConstraint set in the common init or you can use the way above.

```
lazy var ContactName : UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.textColor = UIColor.white
    view.textAlignment = .center
    return view
}()
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.addSubview(ContactName)
    //set your constraints by NSLayoutConstraint
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying I must implement "required init?" function.

Comment: Also, it activates that "required init?" function so I must implement it. Should I copy the body of your init function to it ?

Comment: You dont have to add anything to required init code.

Comment: I added the default "required init?" code and it does activate it, and it is defaulted with "throw exception". Do I need to do anything besides deleting it ?

Comment: I tried adding constraints and it doesn't work. I'm not sure as to what to do next

Comment: I did not check where you added your custom class to table view you should register your custom class to uitableview. You should check this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9NhYx9xIiU) in order to understand the concept of how to code programmatically.